# Self captured by a closure error

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

```
var myGroup = DispatchGroup()

class Place: NSObject, NSCoding {

// Properties
var placeCoordinate: CLLocation!
var placeName: String!

// Methods
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.placeCoordinate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "placeCoordinate") as! CLLocation
    self.placeName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "placeName") as! String
}

init(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    myGroup.enter()
    self.placeCoordinate = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self.placeCoordinate, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            self.placeName = "Unrecognized"
            print(error!)
        } else {
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                self.placeName = (placemark.addressDictionary!["FormattedAddressLines"] as! [String])[1]
                myGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    })
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(placeCoordinate, forKey: "placeCoordinate")
    aCoder.encode(placeName, forKey: "placeName")
}
}
```

I have built this class which uses an `async` function as you can see.

I want to save an array of this object at `UserDefaults`. I found it's impossible to save custom object at UserDefaults so now I'm trying with `NSCoding`.

In the code above I get error:

> self captured by a closure before all members were initialized

In the constructor at line of the of `reverseGeocodeLocation` function.

Need to mention that the following code worked before I added the `NSCoding` part.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[weak self]` `capture list` in `closure` as:

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self.placeCoordinate, completionHandler: {[weak self] (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            //...
        })
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is?

Comment: In order to avoid the retain cycle, self is made weak. Since self is captured by the closure, so it may hold the reference to self even is self is deinitialized and hence the app may crash. So, to avoid this weak reference to self is used. For more on weak references refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48